# app.UseHttpsRedirection() is redirecting to "underlying" hostname not "request" hostname

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

**Background**

I have an Azure App Service hosted at myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net.

The Azure App Service Startup class contains the line app.UseHttpsRedirection().

If I type http://myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net into a browser, it redirects to https://myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net - great!

I have DNS CNAME mydns.mycoolserver.com which references the above App Service.

If I type https://mydns.mycoolserver.com into a browser, then the browser shows my app service, and the address bar of the browser shows **https**://mydns.mycoolserver.com and all is good.

**Problem**

If I type **http://mydns.mycoolserver.com** into a browser, then the address bar of the browser shows **https://*myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net***.

So, it seems to me that the UseHttpsRedirection middleware has worked, but that it is redirecting to the "underlying" hostname, not the "original" hostname.

Note: in reality there is a Standard Akamai CDN in between myazurewebsite and mydns, so mydns is pointing to the CDN endpoint (myazurewebsite.**azureedge**.net) not the actual app service.  Standard Akamai CDN doesn't have a rules engine so it isn't capable of doing http->https redirect, so I assume that it is the app.UseHttpsRedirection that is doing the redirect.

Anyway, in the above scenario, how can I get http://mydns.mycoolserver.com to redirect to https://mydns.mycoolserver.com?

Comment: I tried to create the Akamai CDN and found the same problem. I suggest to seek official help and [raise a support ticket on the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: Thanks @JasonPan.  But is there a way I can do my own https redirection or set a server feature or something to get the app service code to handle the redirection properly?

Comment: I think this is a problem on the cdn side. I suggest you seek offical help from Microsoft .